# teach apt-get to not complain about a particular package

Tags: apt, dpkg

I need to have `xpra 0.15.10` installed on my system because the version that comes with `trusty` doesn't work. Now I downloaded the binary from http://xpra.org/#download which generally works fine only that apt-get wouldn't let me install anything else but complain that I need to run `apt-get -f install` first which will remove `xpra` again i.e. whenever I need to run `apt-get` I need to un- and re-install the `xpra`package - not very convenient I must say. Is there either an option to tell apt-get to not worry about this particular package or manually tell apt-get where to install the `deb` from for this package?

Comment: Please provide the exact, full error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apt-mark` to hold the package so that it does not get updated after you install it.  The command would be from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-mark hold xpra
```

from the manpage for `apt-mark`:

```
   hold
       hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the
       package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.
       The command is only a wrapper around dpkg --set-selections and the
       state is therefore maintained by dpkg(1) and not affected by the
       --file option.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

**aptitude** can be useful for resolving conflicts. **sudo apt-get install aptitude**
It will automatically suggest a few options to resolve any issues. It handles everything to do with apt (install/remove/update etc) with simple keypresses all in the CLI.

If apt-get has problems; then launching aptitude might give you a better understanding (or way of handling it). and avoids having to know most of the uncommon apt-get commands.

If anything is highlighted RED, press E to then examine the solutions. All required keys are shown while in that screen.

https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you would like to propose a solution to the problem at hand, it is best to provide at least a few details of how your proposed solution should work. Rather than just saying "Use `aptitude`", your answer could benefit by explaining the steps needed to take in `aptitude` to quiet the errors.

Comment: Sure! I elaborated a little. Aptitude just happens to be a program that most of the time only needs running to resolve issues.